# Disable user login MacBook Pro Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos

I have a question. How can I disable the login on mac with os yosemite 10.10.2 Everytime when I want to start on the laptop I have to input my password and login. I want to disable this one. I tried to disable from security& Privacy section or users and groups but failure....can somebody help me please

Comment: Hello ! I have a problem. I want to disable login psw but i cannot. I checked and file vault and is enabled , i changed to a diff pass and still AUTOMATIC LOGIN is disabled...and i cannot move it to ON. Please i need assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable Automatic Login in **System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options > Automatic login**.

If the Automatic login function is disabled then according to this *[The WP Guru](http://wpguru.co.uk/2014/08/how-to-enable-automatic-user-login-on-mac-os-x-yosemite/)* post there are two things to check:

- FileVault is not enabled. If it is, you cannot use Automatic login. Check in **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > FileVault**
- You are not using your iCloud password for your Mac account. If you are, change it to a separate password and you should be able to use Automatic login.

Comment: Hello ! I have a problem. I want to disable login psw but i cannot. I checked and file vault and is enabled , i changed to a diff pass and still AUTOMATIC LOGIN is disabled...and i cannot move it to ON. Please i need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you....."You can enable Automatic Login in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options > Automatic login."

A bit more, you need to open the lock and click on your User name. It will request a password. Type in and re-lock

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a password, when it goes your main account, put in your password and when it asks you to put in a new password leave it blank. It'll say, "You have not put in a password for this account". Click on "okay".

Answer (score 0):

Ever since I updated to El Capitan, I can't log in automatically into my user account (without giving password, I mean). Everyone says to uncheck the automatic login button in the `Apple -> System Preferences -> Users & Group -> Option` section. But the automatic login button is shaded grey, so I can't uncheck it, (yes even after I unlock the padlock).

Here is how to enable that checkbox.

1. In the `Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Users & Group` section, the account I wish to automatically log in must be admin. Once on my user I clicked to change my password. It asked if I want to change my iCloud password or change my local password. Change your iCloud password.
2. `Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Security -> FireVault`, make sure  FireVault is disabled (if it isn't, then do so and it'll take several hours).
3. `After FireVault is disabled, goto Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Security -> General` section, unlock the bottom padlock, and you should now have a "deactivate automatic login" that appeared. Uncheck this as it prevents you from doing so.
4. `Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Users & Group -> Options`, the automatic login button should now have your user instead of the "deactivated/disabled".